# How to use BETWEEN inside MIN() / MAX() in createview?

Tags: mysql

So i want to make a createview to separate time record to 4 rows,
but always resulting erron on "MIN(time BETWEEN '11:00:00' and '12:00:00') as checkout," so my question is how to use between inside min() / max() based on my syntax below?

```
CREATE VIEW absenfinal AS SELECT pin, name, date,
        MIN(time) as login,
        MIN(time BETWEEN '11:00:00' and '12:00:00') as checkout,
        MAX(time BETWEEN '11:00:00' and '12:00:00') as checkin,
        MAX(time) as logout
        FROM tb_tgljam
        GROUP BY date, pin;
```

The working code is:

```
 CREATE VIEW absenfinal AS SELECT pin, name, date,
            MIN(time) as login,
            MAX(time) as logout
            FROM tb_tgljam
            GROUP BY date, pin;
```

Comment: Please include sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` clause for the added condition for your aggregate call

```
 MIN(CASE WHEN time BETWEEN '11:00:00' and '12:00:00' THEN time END) as checkout,
```

Comment: @devian You should still include sample data and expected output.  As it stands now, your question will be of little use to anyone else.